# Transferring VBA (Excel) to Microsoft Access Expression Builder

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, expression

I am attempting to translate the following code for Excel into the Expression Builder in Access verbatim but I keep getting an error message telling me that I am missing an ending parenthesis/bracket.

**The Excel code (correct):** `=IFERROR(IF($DH3=0,0,IF(OR($CM3="Live",$CM3="Policy Adjustment"),(($AY3/VLOOKUP($AM3,Maintenance!$A$3:$B$14,2,FALSE))*((VLOOKUP($AM3,Maintenance!$A$3:$B$14,2,FALSE))-DATEDIF($BC3,TODAY(),"M"))),0)),0)`

**Access code (not correct):** `IIf(IsError([Input - Altus]![Months Remaining]=0,0,IIf([Input - Altus]![Status]="Live" OR [Input - Altus]![Status]="Policy Adjustment",(([Input - Altus]![Net Annual Earnings]/[Input - Commission Type]![Indemnity Period (months)])*[Input - Commission Type]![Indemnity Period (months)])-DateDiff("m",[Input - Altus]![Expected Payment Date YTD],Date(),2),0)`

I am new to this so any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: It's quite difficult to decipher that in one continuous line. And I really hope you haven't got a field called [Indemnity Period (months)]  ?  Maybe describe in plain English what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: It looks like you have 8 `(` and 6 `)`. You are missing parenthesis.

Comment: Two things. First, break it down to smaller parts and test individually instead of trying to translate the whole thing. Two, do not use `IsError` to account for `NULL` values or divisions by zero or fields in the wrong format. Use `Nz` for `NULL` testing, `IIF([expression]=0)` to avoid divisions by zero and specific rules for any other testing.

Comment: Additionally as mentioned above you have mismatched parenthesis, Possible Example: `DateDiff("m",[Input - Altus]![Expected Payment Date YTD],Date(),2)`. `DateDiff` only uses 3 parameters for `"m"` (months) the `,2` at the end should not be there. I am assuming it was meant as part of a previous `IIF`

Comment: @SunKnight0 I have included the ,2 because I believe it is indicating Monday (Sunday being first day, 1) under DateDiff's parameters (interval, date 1, date 2, [firstdayofweek], [firstweekofyear]. Could it be that I need to input a [firstweekofyear] value too?

Comment: @SunKnight0 Also, I have edited the code to: IIf(Nz([Input - Altus]![Months Remaining]=0,0,IIf([Input - Altus]![Status]="Live" OR [Input - Altus]![Status]="Policy Adjustment",(([Input - Altus]![Net Annual Earnings]/[Input - Commission Type]![Indemnity Period (months)])*([Input - Commission Type]![Indemnity Period (months)])-DateDiff("m",[Input - Altus]![Expected Payment Date YTD],Date(),2)),0)),0)

The brackets/parenthesis match up in my eyes and on paper but now it's giving the error: The expression you entered has a function containing the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: @Minty Could you explain what is wrong with [Indemnity Period (months)] field?

Comment: The use of special characters, spaces and reserved words in field names or table names makes your life very much harder. The use of parentheses e.g. (month) and a reserved name in a field name will cause you no end of headaches as somewhere down the line when access thinks you are addressing an array with a function name, when you mistype it. It also means you are typing horrendously long  names all the time, and having to surround field names with [ ] . Have a read here for some tips https://www.access-diva.com/d1.html and here https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=225837

Comment: @mcibirka1 Actually the mistake is still there and probably a number of other mistakes. Just because the number of open parentheses match the number of closed ones does not mean they are in the right place. You can keep trying to find the problem through sheer luck or you can follow my first and most important piece of advice which is to break down this 5 line expression to the smallest individually testable part (like just the last `DateDiff`) and build up from there.

Comment: @SunKnight0 Ok I'll try to do that. Should I start from the end of the expression when testing each individual part and build it up going left until I reach the start?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Minty Ok I'll keep that in mind, thanks a lot!

Comment: The goal is to be able to make the smallest start and steps and still get verifiable, meaningful results. I don't know exactly how you environment is set up, but I generally set up a query that gets each individual part as a separate field and then start combining them while still maintaining each step. That allows you to follow through your logic and make sure the results are what you expect, instead of just testing for syntax errors. With complex expressions you can very easily have no errors but still wrong results.